# What are possible reasons that HTML download link is failing?

Tags: php, html, debugging, download, server

I created a page for users to download certain files. I used the HTML download link to do this as so:

`<a download href="/home/Uploads/someDir/someFile.PNG" >View</a>`

This worked fine when I was developing on my laptop with WAMP. When I uploaded the code to our Centos 7 Server it did not work. I changed the Uploads, someDir, and someFile.PNG permissions to 777. I also made sure that the file path was correct. But the when the download link is pressed the file icon at the bottom of the screen says "Failed no file".

Maybe I need to do more with the permissions. I know that the folder that the html file is in has restricted permissions, but I would prefer to keep them that way. I do not know how that could cause an issue.

I am looking for debugging tips/possible causes. At this point I am clueless where to look.

Comment: Without seeing the path to the file I would have to suspect that the path on WAMP is different than the path on your server.

Comment: Web servers have response codes and error logs for a reason.  404 means the path is wrong, 403 means you don't have access, 500 means an internal server error (check logs).

Comment: Is /home/Uploads exposed with the web server?

Comment: Could you please provide the list of contents of /var/www/html from your server.

Answer (score 2):

"Failed no file" has nothing to do with permissions. The path to your download file has most likely changed when the files were uploaded to the server. You should manually check to see if the file at

```
/home/Uploads/someDir/someFile.PNG
```

actually exists. If not you can change the link accordingly or move the download file to the appropriate location.

Comment: The file and directories exist. I'm thinking that it might be due to the fact that the directory is not available to the web server. My understanding is that only the web server will only send files that are in /var/www/html.

Comment: Maybe try moving the download file into the same folder as the HTML or in a child folder. Then change the link accordingly. This should make sure the server can reach the file.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the download not working is simply due to the fact that the path to your file is wrong. My advice on your root directory which is in most cases is var/www/html, create a folder called say somefoldername and manually upload the file to that folder then change the download link to be

```
<a href="somefoldername/someFile.PNG">View</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good alternative to solve this error is to put a dot '.' at the beginning of the url:

```
<a download href="./someDir/someFile.PNG" >View</a>
```

This way you will not need to indicate the complete url.
And if in the future the url changes, you won't have to modify the url.
In my case it works perfect, I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the directory in which you are trying to fetch the file. Your looking file may be not present in that directory. Otherwise, you are using the correct piece of code.

```
<a download href="~/home/Uploads/someDir/someFile.PNG" >View</a>
```